# Conditional independence of binary variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I encountered this problem as an exercise of the probability graphical model:

Show that for binary random variables $(X,Y, Z)$ it holds that
$$
X\perp Y\ and\ X\perp Y|Z \Rightarrow (X,Z)\perp Y\ or\ (X,Y)\perp Z.
$$
Could anyone please give any ideas on it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What approach are you using? My idea is use the property of independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ with joint pmf $f$ that $f(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$.

Comment: I tried this way but I messed up many terms @_@. Maybe you can make it work.